# Error when I encript a text in android studio using kotling

Tags: android, kotlin

Good morning.

I´m having some problem when I want to encrypt a text using SecretKey with AES and a personal key. Before running app, I have´t got any kind of problem but when I run the app, app stops some seconds later. I put and try and catch with a toast for getting the problem but I don´t see any error. I have got to EditTex. One of them is for writting a plain text and the second one is for getting the text encriptep. I´ve got a button and when I press the buttong I want to have the encripted text in the second edittex. I show below my code expecting someone can help me. Regards.

```
package com.example.FirstApp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
  



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //variable para almacenar el texto a encriptar
    var textoEncriptar: String = ""
    val btnEncriptar: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnEncriptar)
    val txtPlano: EditText = findViewById(R.id.txtPlain)
    val txtEncripted: EditText = findViewById(R.id.txtEncriptado)
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnEncriptar.setOnClickListener(){
            textoEncriptar = txtPlano.text.toString()
            encriptar(textoEncriptar)
        }
    }
    fun encriptar(textoEncriptar: String){
        try {
            val claveUsuario: String = "11AA22B4444"
            va clave: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(claveUsuario.toByteArray(), "AES")
            val cifrar: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
            cifrar.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clave)
            var arrayTextoPlano: ByteArray = textoEncriptar.toByteArray()
            var arrayTextoEncriptado: ByteArray = cifrar.doFinal(arrayTextoPlano)
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are any logs available?

Answer (score -1):

The code you've posted seems to have some issues and it's likely the reason your app is crashing. Here are a few things you need to fix:

You are trying to initialize your views (`btnEncriptar`, `txtPlano`, and `txtEncripted`) outside of the `onCreate` method. You should do this inside the `onCreate` method after `setContentView`.

You are trying to find views by their IDs before calling `setContentView`, which will result in `null` references. You should move the view initialization inside the `onCreate` method after `setContentView`.

The key length in your `claveUsuario` string is too short for AES. You need to use a key of the correct length (e.g., 16, 24, or 32 bytes for AES-128, AES-192, or AES-256, respectively).

Here's the corrected code:

```kotlin
package com.example.FirstApp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Variable for storing the text to encrypt
    var textoEncriptar: String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnEncriptar: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnEncriptar)
        val txtPlano: EditText = findViewById(R.id.txtPlain)
        val txtEncripted: EditText = findViewById(R.id.txtEncriptado)

        btnEncriptar.setOnClickListener {
            textoEncriptar = txtPlano.text.toString()
            val encryptedText = encriptar(textoEncriptar)
            txtEncripted.setText(encryptedText)
        }
    }

    fun encriptar(textoEncriptar: String): String {
        try {
            val claveUsuario: String = "11AA22B444411AA22" // 16-byte key for AES-128
            val clave: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(claveUsuario.toByteArray(), "AES")
            val cifrar: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
            cifrar.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clave)
            val arrayTextoPlano: ByteArray = textoEncriptar.toByteArray()
            val arrayTextoEncriptado: ByteArray = cifrar.doFinal(arrayTextoPlano)

            // Convert the encrypted byte array to a hexadecimal string
            val encryptedText = arrayTextoEncriptado.joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
            return encryptedText
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```